# Inconsistent performance when multi-threading with Armadillo and OpenBLAS

Tags: multithreading, linear-algebra, lapack, blas, armadillo

Using `Armadillo` I wrote a matrix-vector multiplication and a linear system solve. Armadillo is compiled from source and uses `OpenBLAS`, also compiled from source. Unfortunately I am getting inconsistent results for single-threaded and multi-threaded runs. The matrix-vector multiplication runs faster on a single-thread while the linear system solve runs faster when multi-threading. I was hoping if someone could give me some pointers on what I am doing wrong.

See below:

- Source codes
- Compile & run bash script
- Results
- System information

**matmul_armadillo.cpp**

```
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    mat A = randu<mat>(n, n);
    vec x = randu<vec>(n);

    A*x;

    return 0;
}
```

**solve_armadillo.cpp**

```
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    mat A = randu<mat>(n, n);
    vec b = randu<vec>(n);
    vec x;

    x = solve(A, b);

    return 0;
}
```

**benchmark.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

g++ matmul_armadillo.cpp -o matmul_armadillo -O3 -march=native -std=c++11 -larmadillo
g++ solve_armadillo.cpp -o solve_armadillo -O3 -march=native -std=c++11 -larmadillo

N=7500

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
echo ''

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=2
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
echo ''

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=3
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
echo ''

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
echo ''

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=5
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
echo ''

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=6
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
echo ''

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=7
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
echo ''

export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=8
echo 'Running matmul_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./matmul_armadillo $N
echo ''
echo 'Running solve_armadillo on' $OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS 'threads'
time ./solve_armadillo $N
```

**Results**

```
$ ./benchmark.sh 
Running matmul_armadillo on 1 threads

real    0m0.943s
user    0m0.628s
sys     0m0.159s

Running solve_armadillo on 1 threads

real    0m13.910s
user    0m13.553s
sys     0m0.300s

Running matmul_armadillo on 2 threads

real    0m1.528s
user    0m1.361s
sys     0m0.402s

Running solve_armadillo on 2 threads

real    0m15.815s
user    0m29.097s
sys     0m1.083s

Running matmul_armadillo on 3 threads

real    0m1.534s
user    0m1.480s
sys     0m0.533s

Running solve_armadillo on 3 threads

real    0m11.729s
user    0m31.022s
sys     0m1.290s

Running matmul_armadillo on 4 threads

real    0m1.543s
user    0m1.619s
sys     0m0.674s

Running solve_armadillo on 4 threads

real    0m10.013s
user    0m34.055s
sys     0m1.696s

Running matmul_armadillo on 5 threads

real    0m1.545s
user    0m1.620s
sys     0m0.664s

Running solve_armadillo on 5 threads

real    0m9.945s
user    0m33.803s
sys     0m1.669s

Running matmul_armadillo on 6 threads

real    0m1.543s
user    0m1.607s
sys     0m0.684s

Running solve_armadillo on 6 threads

real    0m10.069s
user    0m34.283s
sys     0m1.699s

Running matmul_armadillo on 7 threads

real    0m1.542s
user    0m1.622s
sys     0m0.661s

Running solve_armadillo on 7 threads

real    0m10.041s
user    0m34.154s
sys     0m1.704s

Running matmul_armadillo on 8 threads

real    0m1.546s
user    0m1.576s
sys     0m0.712s

Running solve_armadillo on 8 threads

real    0m10.123s
user    0m34.492s
sys     0m1.697s
```

**System information**

- openSUSE 13.1 64 bit
- Armadillo 4.100.2 (compiled from source)
- OpenBLAS 0.2.8 (compiled from source)

Comment: you may want to visit the [OpenBLAS wiki](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues), as you're more likely to get a response there

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that

```cpp
A*x;
```

may have been optimized away because you do not do anything with the result. The delayed evaluation template magic of the multiplication operation in Armadillo can easily bring about that the Lapack routine for the computation is never called.  So if you enable threading, you only measure the overhead of setting that up. Hence your program executes more quickly with threading disabled.

With

```cpp
x = solve(A, b);
```

it is different as that leads pretty directly to the respective Lapack call, which probably cannot be optimized away as the compiler cannot rule out side effects and you actually assign the result to a variable. The `solve` call benefits from multiprocessing for such large matrices.

To fix your benchmark your should do two things:

- Make use of the results of a computation to stop the optimizer from doing too much
- Repeat the computation several times to get better statistics and reduce the influence of initial set-up cost

Here is an untested example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    mat A = randu<mat>(n, n);
    vec x = randu<vec>(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        x = A*x;
    }
    x.print(std::cout);

    return 0;
}
```

The `print` call may not be necessary.